# How to fill a data to a text box when grid view is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have a grid view displaying search results.

Once a field is selected, the data should be displayed in text boxes.

What's the code to fill text boxes when a row of a data grid view is clicked?

I've tried the code that is shown below. It returns an error.

```
TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow[0].Cell[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow doesn't exist to write code for you, it exists to help you fix code you're having problems with.

Comment: Wingaurdium.Leviosa();

Comment: Are you trying to put the row of a `GridView` into edit mode?

Comment: TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow[0].Cell[1].Value.ToString();

Returns an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Index of Currently Selected Row in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578144/index-of-currently-selected-row-in-datagridview)

There you have all you want.

Next time try to use google, or *search* on that site, before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Gridview has lot of events associated with it. based on the location of the text boxes, you may want to use RowEditing event or SelectedIndexChanged event.