# How to display rowcount in a textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using `Textbox1.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount()` to display(in Textbox1) the total number of items in the datagridview on my vb.net app. Now i want Textbox2 to display the position at the datagridview. How will i do that? Eg I want something like 6 out of 50. So "6" will be displayed at Textbox1. Are you getting me?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index of Currently Selected Row in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578144/index-of-currently-selected-row-in-datagridview)

Comment: @ Werdna Textbox2.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow() but am getting Error 1 Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: why not try making an integer and then converting the integer to a string with a veritable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle that in the below event

```
Private Sub dgv_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv.SelectionChanged   
    If dgv.CurrentRow isnot Nothing
       Textbox1.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Index + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this is working but 1. It seems its starting to count from zero and i would like it to start counting at one. 2. I wish this could be shown in a textbox instead of a messagebox. Kindly assist.

Comment: @HenryGathigira I updated the code; in programming the count usually starts from 0

Comment: Awsome. You are the Best. And a genius too. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount

    i = +i

    Textbox1.Text = i

Next
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index` property.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. That's the error am getting.

Comment: Use `If` to check if `CurrentRow` is `null`. Come on. That is pretty basic.

Comment: Yeah I know its basic but i am also so new in vb. Did somebody get my question? If code 1 is working i know code 2 can work too. Somebody just assist. I am pretty tired. In other words i want the code behind binding navigator "position" textbox.