# How to get the selected row index from an asp.net gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview with no datakeys.  When I click the row edit button, I'm taken to the rowediting method.  I've tried several ways to get the row index, but no luck.

```
   protected void gvwCustomerLocation_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
   {
        var index1 = e.NewEditIndex;  //gives me an incorrect index number

        //The SelectedIndex always equals -1
        for (int i = 0; i < gvwCustomerLocation.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (gvwCustomerLocation.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {

            }
        }

        int index = gvwCustomerLocation.EditIndex;  //The EditIndex = -1

        GridViewRow row = gvwCustomerLocation.SelectedRow;  //The SelectedRow = null
        var test = row.RowIndex.ToString();
   }
```

How can I get the selected row index?

Comment: You should be able to use [e.NewEditIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewediteventargs.neweditindex(v=vs.110).aspx) and `gvwCustomerLocation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]` to get the selected row.

Comment: @DaveAnderson Unfortunately, it doesn't.  When I click the first row in my gridview, the value of index1 is 2 instead of 0.

Comment: What is your GridView data binding what data is in the row when you use `gvwCustomerLocation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]`?

Comment: @DaveAnderson It's binding to a DataSet table.

Comment: How many rows does your data set have? If `e.NewEditIndex = 2` which row in your data set is it? How have you wired up the event handlers?

Comment: @DaveAnderson In this case, my data set only has 4 row.  When my gridview index is two, it is referring to my data set record at index 0.  I'm not sure which event handler you are referring to.

Comment: So the index isn't what you expected but you get the row you edit? If you are trying to get back to the bound data this is where you need to have DataKeys bound. What are you using the index for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index of Currently Selected Row in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578144/index-of-currently-selected-row-in-datagridview)

Comment: Please check this solution

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI  This isn't a datagridview.

Comment: read with opening eyes GridViewRow row = gvwCustomerLocation.SelectedRow;

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI  Your solution doesn't apply.  Read with opening eyes yourself.

Comment: @DaveAnderson  Thanks for your help.  I posted my solution below.

Comment: @user9889878 but I am not here to argue.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up on getting a row index from my gridview and decided to make a primary key in my sql server result set to use as my key in the front end.